# How to get different URLs pointing to same servlet?

Tags: scala, servlets

I am absolutely new in Servlet technology and this is *absolutely basic* question, but I am all confused by the tutorials that are all too complicated for me.

I have a new servlet `HelloWorldServlet`. In `web.xml`, I have this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
     PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN"
     "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">

<web-app>
     <servlet>
         <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>cz.hello.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/HelloWorldServlet</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

`HelloWorldServlet.scala` (I prefer scala to java) looks like this

```
package cz.hello

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

 class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    override def doGet(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse) = {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain")
        resp.getWriter.println("Hello, world")
    }
}
```

So far so good, servlet is loaded using Jetty, I am happy, I can see "hello world" on `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlet`.

Now, I want the servlet to be able to react to GET requests to, say, `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlet/hello` and `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlet/goodbye` and to both of them differently. For example like (pseudocode)

```
    override def doGet(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse) = {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain")
        if (req.isAddress("/hello") {
            resp.getWriter.println("Hello, world")
        } else {
            resp.getWriter.println("Goodbye, world")
        }
    }
```

How can acchieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you want to react to POST requests, you should implement the `doPost` method, instead of the `doGet`.

Second, I would advise you to think about handling each URL in a different servlet, unless your code will be as simple as the example you provided.

Chances are your code will get more complex when developing real-world applications, so it would be much cleaner if you separate the responsibilities into two servlets. If you agree with this approach, it is just a matter of creating another `<servlet>` and another `<servlet-mapping>` object in your `web.xml`, like follows:

```
<web-app>
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>cz.hello.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>GoodbyeWorldServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>cz.hello.GoodbyeWorldServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>GoodbyeWorldServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/goodbye</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This way, requests to `/hello` will be handled by `HelloWorldServlet`, and requests to `/goodbye` will be handled by `GoodbyeWorldServlet`. Now it is just a matter of defining whether GET or POST makes more sense for you and implementing the corresponding methods(`doGet` or `doPost`, or both) at your servlets.

Your idea (comparing the contents of the URL inside the servlet) also works, but is not a good design, since you might end up with a huge if/then/else chain, which sounds like a bad idea in this case.

Comment: Oh, OK. So, the recomended design is to have more classes for different kind of responsibility, OK? (The POST thing was a mistake)

Comment: For sure. Let's say your application is a simple CRUD, dealing with users and groups, for example. You will have two URLs (/users and /groups), handled by two servlets. In these servlets, you would implement doGet (for retrieving users/groups), doDelete (for removing), doPut (for creating) and doPost (for updating). This is just a silly example that can make you understand the basics behind the idea.

Comment: No, that's a great example and what I needed.